# Using multiple CPUs for a very fast function in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

What I have is a function that can be looped 10,000 times in 1 second. However, I need to perform this function tens to hundreds of millions of times. As expected due to the overhead of using CPUs, using the native `multiprocessing` package with my 4 cores slows the 10k loop to 1.5 seconds.  Using the chunksize parameter in `multiprocessing` helped trivially. Is there any way to get multiple processes to call this function with a speedup greater than the overhead?

A truncated version of the function:

```
rands = np.random.random((200, 1000000))

def randfunc(i):
    Q = np.concatenate([rands[:,[i]], rands[:,[i]] * rands[:,[i+1]]],axis=1)
    Q2 = np.dot(np.transpose(Q),Q)
    Q3 = np.linalg.inv(Q2) * Q2[1,1]
    return Q3
```

Comment: Are you using Windows or a Unix OS?

Comment: I have access to both Windows and Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cut the run time in half by using the `ipyparallel` package simply using `map_sync` instead of the `multiprocessing` package to parallelize the function. I'm not really sure why the former package has less overhead than the latter, but for the former, loading the data did take long, as opposed to the latter, which recognizes `rands` as a variable during parallel execution. However, in both cases the data are stored in RAM. If anyone reads this and knows the reason why `ipyparallel` is faster, do comment.